# i need to get this json output { "data": [ ["Airi",12], ["Angelica",32], ["mali",24] ] }

Tags: php, json

i need to get this json output by arrays

```
{ "data": [ ["Airi",12], ["Angelica",32], ["mali",24] ] }
```

Comment: What outcome do you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: what prevent you to have this ?

Comment: Can we have the source php code which exactly has this data array?

Comment: Look up PHP's `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions. Then come back when you've tried them.

Comment: i need this output { "data": [ ["Airi",12], ["Angelica",32], ["mali",24] ] } i getting value from sql database.     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($strSQL_Result))
    {             
        $data['data'][] =$row['name'];        
       
    }
     array_push($result, $data);
    echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$array = array('data' => array('Airi' => 12, 'Angelica' => 32, 'mali'=> 24));
$array = json_encode($array);
print_r($array);
```